# Query with Group and name sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a SQL query that is bit more complicated to what I am used to writing.

Example data:

```
event_id    event_source duration   name
67538576    9071         67         [Lpr] abc
67371890    9071         62         [Lpr] Test data
67338632    9071         63         [Lpr] Test data
67331147    9071         63         [Lpr] Test data
67325698    9071         235        [Lpr] Test data
63098403    9071         2733441    [Lpr] Test data diff
63023403    8001         2241       [Cam] Some name
63013203    8001         212        [Cam] Some name
62013203    7000         60         [Lpr] Name B
62012203    7000         70         [Lpr] Name B
```

So far I have a working query

```
SELECT min(name) as name ,sum(duration) as TotalDuration
FROM table
WHERE duration > 30 AND name LIKE '[[]Lpr]%'
GROUP BY event_source
ORDER BY TotalDuration Desc
```

Currently it will return

```
Name            TotalDuration
[Lpr] Test data 2733931
[Lpr] Name B    130
```

But I would like that query to always returns the names with biggest event_id, so good results would be "[Lpr] abc" and "[Lpr] Name B".

Comment: Desired results for your sample data and a clear description will help.

Comment: why not [Lpr] Test data diff, as it is having the longest duration ?

Comment: Currently result looks like:
Name                 TotalDuration
[Lpr] Test Data    2733931

But i would like to sort Name, and return one with biggest event_id, as names can change over time

Comment: Why don't you add `max(event_id)` in your query ? [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1dea62e716dc282f186488eaf64c7cb8)

Comment: I added more test data, hopefully it will clear things up bit more. There would be multiple results, but some are with wrong names (old ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so

```
SELECT  T1.name,
        T2.TotalDuration
FROM table T1  INNER JOIN 
( SELECT max(event_id) as event_id,sum(duration) as TotalDuration
  FROM table
  WHERE duration > 30 AND name LIKE '[[]Lpr]%'
  GROUP BY event_source ) T2 
ON T1.event_id = T2.event_id 
ORDER BY T2.TotalDuration Desc
```

or you can use the window function [win function sum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_SUM.html)

Sorry for the mistake  :)

Comment: Seems like this solution is the "simplest" that i can understand. i had to add "DISTINCT" to T1.name, otherwise i got some duplicated entires when compared to first script. But after adding it they both performed with same results. Since i understand this one better il mark this as solution. Many thanks to O'tkir Xo'jayev and Stu.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can make use of window analytic functions:

```
select name, TotalDuration 
from (
  select *,
    Sum(duration) over(partition by event_source) TotalDuration, 
    Row_Number() over(partition by event_source order by event_id desc) rn
  from t
  where duration > 30 and name LIKE '[[]Lpr]%'
)t
where rn = 1
order by TotalDuration desc;
```